# react + semantic ui: access column width

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm using the [grid component](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid/#types-grid), and according to the doc, the `Row.Column` component has a `width` attribute, that I'd like to access.

```
class MainGrid extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Row columns={2}>
          <Grid.Column>
            <JsonEditor
              width={???} // <---- I'd like to set the width property with the column's width property
            />
          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>

        <Grid.Row columns={1}>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

If I understand correctly, it's fine to use a `Row.Column` property for my `JsonEditor` component, because it's passing a property from a parent to a child. But I cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: what about if you set the `Grid.Column` `width` and make `JsonEditor` `width 100%` ?

Comment: The `JsonEditor`'s `width` property is in pixels unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming JsonEditor is a wrapper for the [react-ace editor](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace), you should be able to set width to `100%` to get an editor the full width of the containing column. [The value is passed to the style attribute verbatim](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/blob/master/src/ace.js#L304-L311).

This means [@kyaw-siesein](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014019/react-semantic-ui-access-column-width#comment90979778_52014019)'s suggestion is on the money!